# If $x\geq 0,$ what is the smallest value of the function $f(x)= \frac{4x^2+ 8x + 13}{6(1+ x)}$

Tags: calculus, functions, graphing-functions

If $x\geq 0,$ what is the smallest value of the function
$$f(x)= \frac{4x^2+ 8x + 13}{6(1+ x)}$$
I tried doing it by completing the square in numerator and making it of the form
$$\frac{4(x+ 1)^2+ 9}{6(1+ x)}$$
and then, I put the value of $x= 0$ and the answer is coming out to be $13/6.$

But the actual answer is $2.$

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Take the derivative, set it to zero, find $x$.  Use the second derivative to see if it is a local *maximum* or *minimum*.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thank you so much! If you don't mind, can you also tell what's wrong with the way i am approaching it?

Comment: You are solving for where the function is $0$.  Very different problem.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much!

Comment: No derivatives needed. $(a-b)^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab \geq 0$ is enough to find the minimum.

Answer (score 4):

After completing the squares you can use the inequality between the arithmetic and geometric mean (AM-GM) in the form $a^2+b^2 \geq 2ab$:

Hence,

$$\frac{(2(x+1))^2+3^2}{6(x+1)}\stackrel{AM-GM}{\geq}\frac{2\cdot 2(x+1)\cdot 3}{6(x+1)}=2$$

Equality is reached for $2(x+1)=3 \Leftrightarrow x = \frac 12$.

Comment: Oh, that made it much simpler...Thank You

Comment: @AhmedFaraz You are welcome and 3fwan :-)

Answer (score 1):

The derivative, $$\frac{2}{3}-\frac{3}{2 (x+1)^2}$$ is zero when $x=1/2$:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $x+1=y^2$  as $x\ge0, y^2\ge1$

$$\dfrac{4x^2+8x+13}{1+x}=\dfrac{4(y^2-1)^2+8(y^2-1)+13}{y^2}=4y^2+\dfrac9{y^2}=\left(2y-\dfrac3y\right)^2+2\cdot2y\cdot\dfrac3y\ge12$$  the equality occurs if $2y-\dfrac3y=0\iff y^2=\dfrac32\iff x=?$